# Is nginx needed if Express used

Tags: express, nginx

I have a nodeJS web application with Express running on a Digital Ocean droplet.The nodeJs application provides back-end API's. I have two react front-ends that utilise the API's with different domains. The front-ends can be hosted on the same server, but my developer tells me I should use another server to host the front-ends, such as cloudflare.
I have read that nginX can enable hosting multiple sites on the same server (i.e. host my front-ends on same server) but unsure if this is good practice as I then may not be able to use cloudflare.

In terms of security could someone tell me If I need nginx, and my options please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way too open-ended question but I will try to answer it:

> In terms of security could someone tell me If I need nginx, and my
> options please?

**You will need Nginx (or Apache) on both scenarios**. With one or multiple servers, using Express or not, Express is only an application framework to build routes but you still need a service that will respond to network requests, this is what Nginx and Apache do.

You could avoid using Nginx but then, your users would have to make the request directly to the port where you started Express. For example: *http://my-site.com:3000/welcome* In terms of security, you would better hide the port number and [use a Nginx's reverse proxy](https://hackernoon.com/configure-nginx-s-a-reverse-proxy-for-your-nodejs-application-9tk032e8) so that your users will only need to browse *http://my-site.com/welcome*.

> my developer tells me I should use another server to host the
> front-ends, such as cloudflare

Cloudflare does not offer hosting services as of today. It does offer CDN to host a few files but not a full site. You would need another Digital Ocean instance to do so. In a [Cloudflare's forum post](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/does-cloudflare-provide-hosting/84490) I found: *"Cloudflare is not a host. Cloudflare’s basic service is a DNS provider, where you simply point to your existing host."*.

> I have read that nginX can enable hosting multiple sites on the same
> server

Yes, Nginx (and Apache too) can host multiple sites, with different names or the same name, as domains (*[www.my-backend.com](http://www.my-backend.com)*, *[www.my-frontend.com](http://www.my-frontend.com)*) or subdomains (*[www.backend.my-site.com](http://www.backend.my-site.com)*, *[www.my-site.com](http://www.my-site.com)*) in the same server.

> ... but unsure if this is good practice

It is definitively not a bad practice, it is very common to separate applications on different subdomains. A few valid reasons to keep them in separated servers would be:

- Because you want that if the front-end fails the back-end API continues to work.
- Because you want to balance network traffic.
- Because you want simply want to keep them separated (the microservices architecture).

It would be a bad practice to abuse from these microservices (i.e. a microservice to get the value of PI)

Comment: Thanks, but Express acts as a server, I've been listening to ports.

Comment: Yes, you can just listen to the ports. The problem is when you want your users to go to that site. That's when they have to go to _site.com:3000_ or so. On the other hand, if that is not a problem then I think there is definitively no need to set up an Nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info earlier, I want to host the api server (apiSite.com) which can run on any port, but should be SSL secured and two public facing front-ends (site1.com and site2.com) also on SSL. Ideally, Option 1, to host the 3 sites on a single server, however it depends on the complexity. Option 2, I could host the front-ends on a cheap static hosting provider. I wanted to know technically what the two options involve.